# Python error in sorting a list

Tags: python, sorting

I simply want to sort a list... and I have a 2 parameter lambda
Here is my simple code:

```
I.sort(key = lambda x, y: x.finish - y.finish)
```

And the compiler return this error

```
builtins.TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

Comment: You can't use a two parameter lambda as the key for sort. It passes in each item one at a time.

Comment: You are confusing the `cmp` and `key` arguments; `cmp` is entirely gone from Python 3. For `key`, just use `key=lambda x: x.finish`

Comment: What does your list look like?

Comment: it is a list of time interval... def__init__(self, title, start, finish):

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use `key` function as a `cmp` function (removed in Python 3.x), but don't you mean to simply sort by the "finish" attribute:

```
I.sort(key=lambda x: x.finish)
```

Or, with the ["attrgetter"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter):

```
from operator import attrgetter

I.sort(key=attrgetter("finish"))
```

Comment: thanks for the quick... What I want to do, is to sort by the interval of two finish